# import main project file in referenced project ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, three20

I integrated three20 project in my app. I want to go back to the called class. But unable to import that class.
This is what i do in TTPhotoViewController:

```
MainMenuVC *mmenu = [[MainMenuVC alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mmenu animated:YES];
[mmenu release];
```

But xcode cant file this class. "Use of undeclared identifier..."

I tried to import like the following, but none worked:

```
#import <MyApp/MainMenuVC.h>
#import "MyApp/MainMenuVC.h"
#import <../MyApp/MainMenuVC.h>
```

Comment: #import "MainMenuVC.h"   have you tried?

Comment: Even tired this too. But not worked.
#import "MainMenuVC.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have to tried this

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController animated:YES];
```

You cannot import class files vice versa that means.
If you import class B in class A like this: import "B"
you cannot import class  A in class B like this: import "A"
instead use @class "A" in .h file

Comment: Already tired the following, but didnt worked.

'    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [[self parentViewController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; '

Comment: Thanks Sumanth. I add the @class in the .h file. then did :
 MainMenuVC *mmenu = [[MainMenuVC alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mmenu animated:YES];
[mmenu release]; 

it worked.

Comment: If you get the solution you need to accept the answer by clicking tick mark and upvote the answer